# How does one convert a CGImageRef to a CGDataProviderRef?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using a library that needs a CGDataProviderRef however I know how to get a CGImageRef from an image.

```
NSData* data = ... get raw image data from somewhere (PNG, JPEG, etc.) ...;
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
```

How do I convert imageRef to a CGDataProviderRef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

You use the `CGDataProvider` functions to create a `CGDataProviderRef`, then pass that to the library.

See the `CGDataProvider` reference, and in particular:

`CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData`,
`CGDataProviderCreateWithData`,
`CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename`,

```
CGDataProviderCreateWithURL
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **not** converting it to a `CGImageRef first? From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html)

```
CGDataProviderRef CGDataProviderCreateWithData (
    void *info,
    const void *data,
    size_t size,
    CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback releaseData
);
```

If this method does not work for your situation, there are several other `CGDataProviderCreateWithXXXXX` methods pointed out in the docs which may.